# stream stdout to file without increase file size

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, debian

I have a small application, which streams a lot of lines via stdout. After 30 minutes, my disk is full. Any ideas how I can stream the stdout to a file and "tail" it is the same time on another application?

Currently, I have to push the stdout to a file, but it increases a lot

```
    node app.js>/tmp/p
    tail -f /tmp/p
```

but with this, I have a disk problem any ideas would be awesome

Comment: This might help: [How do you keep only the last n lines of a log file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310860)

Comment: You could do this with a [named pipe](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156). Be careful though, if you stop reading from the pipe, the writing application will eventually block.

Comment: this is absolutely awesome @larsks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tee` read from standard input and write to standard output and files:

```
node app.js | tee /tmp/p
```

You can truncate the file `/tmp/p` as you please without interrupting your stdout stream.

Another option would be to double buffer, write x lines to a set of fixed rotating set of files.  `split --filter=...` with a suitable script would do it.  For example:

```
node app.js | split -d --filter='cat > $((${FILE/x} % 2))'
```

You want to set `-a` sufficiently large that you don't run out of
numbers (default is 2; so 99 files), and adjust `-l` to more than 1000 probably.  It blows out if it runs out of sequence numbers, though, so maybe just write a script?  double_buffer:

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix=$1
if [ -z "$prefix" ]
then
    echo usage: double-buffer prefix [lines] [sequences]
    exit 1
fi
lines=${2-1000}
sequences=${3-2}
sequence=0
line=0
while read
do
    if [ "$(echo "$line % $lines" | bc)" -eq 0 ]
    then
        if [ "$line" -ne 0 ]
        then
            sequence=$(echo "($sequence + 1) % $sequences" | bc)
        fi
        : > "$prefix-$sequence"
    fi
    echo "$REPLY" >> "$prefix-$sequence" 
    line=$(echo "$line+1" | bc)
done
```

which you would call with:

```
node app.js | double_buffer /tmp/p 5000 3
```

To write 5k lines to /tmp/p-0, then the next 5k lines to p-1, then p-2 then overwrite p-0 etc.  bc is arbitrary precision unlike bash integers which max out at 2^63.